# Error - Could not fetch url: https://www.google.com/search?num=20&q="searchquery"

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Background**

I'm using Google Sheets to check whether a series of strings appear in Google searches:

```
=IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://www.google.com/search?num=20&q=",CHAR(34), A1, CHAR(34)), CONCATENATE("count(//span[contains(., '",A1,"')])")),"THINKING")
```

Once a count is returned, the next cell goes through the same procedure and so on.

**Issue**

However, after a varying number of queries, the next cell shows:

> Error - Could not fetch url:
>   https://www.google.com/search?num=20&q="searchquery"

**Attempted Solutions**

I've tried finding the reason for this, but cannot so far. A few things to point out:

- This used to work perfectly about 1.5months ago - not sure what has changed since then on Google's side
- Sometimes this occurs on the very first query, indicating that the issue likely isn't about frequency of requests.
- Also, this very same task worked fine a month ago, cascading through hundreds of requests. I've tried running this on the Old Google Sheet, but that is limited to 50 XML requests.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please give an example of the content of the cell `A1`. Better yet, an example that triggered the error you describe, if you could find out what did - versus an example that did not.

Comment: By the way, as far as I know, the new Sheets is also limited to 50 calls to `IMPORTXML()` - is it not?

Comment: Mathias: I believe it is not - I've never had an issue with this before, I've gotten it to work with thousands of calls in a single sheet.

As for the example of A1 content, they are standard strings, such as "Adidas".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a string "THINKING" at the end of your XPath expression - which should not be there really, I assume.

```
=IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://www.google.com/search?num=20&q=",CHAR(34), "Adidas", CHAR(34)), CONCATENATE("count(//span[contains(., '", "Adidas" ,"')])"))
```

Perhaps you meant to add the string "THINKING" outside of the call to `IMPORTXML()`?

But the really curious thing about it is that the formula above returns

```
5
```

whereas a simplified version of the same (doing away with the concatenations):

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?num=20&q='Adidas'", "count(//span[contains(., 'Adidas')])")
```

yields

```
6
```

Comment: Thank you for that - and you're absolutely right. I didn't realize I could add quotations without putting CHAR(34), though I'm not entirely sure why there would be a difference either.

However, I still haven't found a way to avoid the 'NA: Could not fetch url' error - it seems to be happening more often at certain times of day, so I'm assuming it's a server-side problem. 

Do you b by any chance know of a way I could automatically get a cell to re-perform the xmlimport if it encounters an error the first time?

Comment: @Sekoul I agree that your formulae are not at fault, and `IMPORTXML()` is known to be exceptionally buggy anyway in the new Sheets. Also, it is not sophisticated enough to allow you proper error handling in my opinion, except perhaps with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview).

Comment: Great - I'll redo everything on Apps Script to try to deal with the error. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

I was having the same issue right now with my googlesheet and allowing flash on the site solved the problem.